# Get item corresponding to another item from json in php

Tags: php, json

I want to read this JSON using PHP:

```
{
["person":{
   {"name":"Bill"},  
   {"age":"56"},
   {"city":"Houston"}
}],
["person":{  
   {"name":"Jack"},
   {"age":"45"},
   {"city":"Dallas"}
}],
["person":{
   {"name":"Henry"},
   {"age":"33"},
   {"city":"Atlanta"}
}]
}
```

Now I want to look for the person who's name is Jack and get the city he lives in. I know how to check for the name. But how can I get the corresponding city then?

Comment: Can you show how you're checking for the name?

Comment: Ok I think got it, look:

Answer (score 0):

I think this should make it:

```
$string = file_get_contents("persons.json");
$json = json_decode($string);

foreach ($json->person as $person) {
   if($person->name == "Jack")
  {
      $city = $person->city;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I see in your example combination of objects and arrays and you treat them all as objects.... I'm quite sure you'll get at least two errors...

Comment: And your JSON isn't properly formated... Is this just part of document in your question? It should be structured as `{ "name":______ (value,array or object), "name2":_____ }`